# How to reload screen flow (hosted on a record page) when the record is updated?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, aura, screen-flow

Our screen flow, that lives on the record detail lightning page, contains an aura component that displays a progress indicator. This flow needs to be reloaded (must start from the first element) when it detects the record has been updated.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Perhaps by listening to some event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to `force:refreshView` with an `aura:handler`. So, whenever the record gets updated this event will be fired. Here is a simple example. In this example, you can write your logic inside `refreshCmp` JS method.

*markup*

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:availableForFlowScreens">
    <aura:attribute name="setOnInit" type="String" default="default value" />
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.refreshCmp}" />
    <p><b>{!v.setOnInit}</b></p>
</aura:component>
```

*Controller*

```
({
    refreshCmp: function(cmp) {
        cmp.set("v.setOnInit", "Updated Value");
    }
})
```